# Calculate age from birthdate in php 5.2

Tags: php

i can't upgrade my php to 5.3 due to upgrade costs and such. Anyone knows how to calculate age using birthdate in php 5.2 ?

I made a simple form that takes in the day month and year of a person's birthdate in select boxes. it goes in the form of dd,mm,yyyy. When submitted, the function should calculate the age of the person.

Calculate Age

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$d=$_POST['day'];
$m=$_POST['month'];
$y=$_POST['year'];

//converting Inputed DOB in "dd-mm-yyyy" format
$dob=$d.' '.$m.' '.$y;

//Create a new date object with current system date
//$bday=new DateTime($dob);

//Differentiating both dates
//$age = $bday->diff(new DateTime);

//$birthdate = mysql_prep($dob);
//$c_age = $age->y; 

//$dob = new DateTime('$dob');

$dob = new DateTime('$dob');
$now = new DateTime('now');

echo year_diff($now, $dob);

function year_diff($date1, $date2) {
    list($year1, $dayOfYear1) = explode(' ', $date1->format('Y z'));
    list($year2, $dayOfYear2) = explode(' ', $date2->format('Y z'));
    return $year1 - $year2 - ($dayOfYear1 < $dayOfYear2);
}

}
?>


<form action="testage.php" method="post">

Date Of Birth:<br />
                                    <td>Day<br/>
                                        <select name="day"> <!-- To Select Day -->
                                            <option value="01" selected="selected">01</option>
                                            <option value="02">02</option>
                                            <option value="03">03</option>
                                            <option value="04">04</option>
                                            <option value="05">05</option>
                                            <option value="06">06</option>
                                            <option value="07">07</option>
                                            <option value="08">08</option>
                                            <option value="09">09</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                            <option value="12">12</option>
                                            <option value="13">13</option>
                                            <option value="14">14</option>
                                            <option value="15">15</option>
                                            <option value="16">16</option>
                                            <option value="17">17</option>
                                            <option value="18">18</option>
                                            <option value="19">19</option>
                                            <option value="20">20</option>
                                            <option value="21">21</option>
                                            <option value="22">22</option>
                                            <option value="23">23</option>
                                            <option value="24">24</option>
                                            <option value="25">25</option>
                                            <option value="26">26</option>
                                            <option value="27">27</option>
                                            <option value="28">28</option>
                                            <option value="29">29</option>
                                            <option value="30">30</option>
                                            <option value="31">31</option>
                                            <option value="32">32</option>
                                        </select>

                                        Month
                                        <select name="month"><!--TO Select Month-->
                                            <option value="01" selected="selected">Jan</option>
                                            <option value="02">Feb</option>
                                            <option value="03">Mar</option>
                                            <option value="04">Apr</option>
                                            <option value="05">May</option>
                                            <option value="06">Jun</option>
                                            <option value="07">Jul</option>
                                            <option value="08">Aug</option>
                                            <option value="09">Sep</option>
                                            <option value="10">Oct</option>
                                            <option value="11">Nov</option>
                                            <option value="12">Dec</option>
                                        </select>

                                        Year
                                        <select name="year"><!--To Select Year-->
                                            <option value="2013" selected="selected">2013</option>
                                            <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                            <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                            <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                            <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                            <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                            <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                            <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                            <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                            <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                            <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                            <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                            <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                            <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                            <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                            <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                            <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                            <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                            <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                            <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                            <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                            <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                            <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                            <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                            <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                            <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                            <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                            <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                            <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                            <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                            <option value="1983">1983</option>
                                            <option value="1982">1982</option>
                                            <option value="1981">1981</option>
                                            <option value="1980">1980</option>
                                            <option value="1979">1979</option>
                                            <option value="1978">1978</option>
                                            <option value="1977">1977</option>
                                            <option value="1976">1976</option>
                                            <option value="1975">1975</option>
                                            <option value="1974">1974</option>
                                            <option value="1973">1973</option>
                                            <option value="1972">1972</option>
                                            <option value="1971">1971</option>
                                            <option value="1970">1970</option>
                                            <option value="1969">1969</option>
                                            <option value="1968">1968</option>
                                            <option value="1967">1967</option>
                                            <option value="1966">1966</option>
                                            <option value="1965">1965</option>
                                            <option value="1964">1964</option>
                                            <option value="1963">1963</option>
                                            <option value="1962">1962</option>
                                            <option value="1961">1961</option>
                                            <option value="1960">1960</option>
                                            <option value="1959">1959</option>
                                            <option value="1958">1958</option>
                                            <option value="1957">1957</option>
                                            <option value="1956">1956</option>
                                            <option value="1955">1955</option>
                                            <option value="1954">1954</option>
                                            <option value="1953">1953</option>
                                            <option value="1952">1952</option>
                                            <option value="1951">1951</option>
                                            <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                            <option value="1949">1949</option>
                                            <option value="1948">1948</option>
                                            <option value="1947">1947</option>
                                            <option value="1946">1946</option>
                                            <option value="1945">1945</option>
                                            <option value="1944">1944</option>
                                            <option value="1943">1943</option>
                                            <option value="1942">1942</option>
                                            <option value="1941">1941</option>
                                            <option value="1940">1940</option>
                                            <option value="1939">1939</option>
                                            <option value="1938">1938</option>
                                            <option value="1937">1937</option>
                                        </select>

                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
                                        </form>
```

Comment: You should probably use loops for all of these `<option>`'s

Comment: Due to "upgrade costs"? Change hosting providers. Now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is correct.

```
function CurrentAge($d, $m, $y)
{
   $years  = date('Y') - $y;
   $months = date('m') - $m;
   $days   = date('d') - $d;

   if (substr($months, 0, 1) == '-') {
      $years = $years - 1;
      $months = 12 - substr($months, 1);
   }

   if (substr($days, 0, 1) == '-') {
      $days = date('t') - substr($days, 1);
   }

   return $years;
}

echo CurrentAge('21', '02', '1993');
```

Comment: No problem dude, You could also return the users age in years months and days by using return "{$years} years, {$months} months and {$days} old";

Comment: ahhh i see, Thank you once again =)

Comment: Erm. Let's say my birthdate is now an input of 19-03-1994. How do i split that birthdate input back into $d $m and $y ? as in from a variable input of $birthdate that is in a database. Then how do i split up them again?

Comment: $bday = '19-03-1994'; $ex = explode('-', $bday); echo CurrentAge($ex['0'], $ex['1'], $ex['2']);

Comment: strangely, i used only the function and the code you gave me, but i got a blank for an answer O.O

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CUS1LM8h

Comment: Ahh thank you very much that helped. im able to calculate it now. Thanks =)